# Does the removeAllObjects method of an NSArray or NSMutableArray release memory?

Tags: ios, objective-c, memory-management, memory-leaks, nsarray

I need to know if the removeAllObjects method of an NSArray or NSMutableArray releases memory.

If my array has got 10000 elements.
Can I use the

```
[array removeAllObjects];
```

to release the memory and reload it with other elements? Or it leaks memory?

Thanks

EXAMPLE
**if the size of my NSMutable array is 20mb with 10.000 elements for example... if I use the removeAllObjects method...will its size  be 0mb?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An NS[Mutable]Array is a collection of references to object. Calling `-removeAllObjects` nils those references. The capacity and memory used by the array itself stay the same. In the case of NSMutableArray, those references can be reused to point to other objects. NSArray lacks the method `-removeAllObjects` because it's not mutable.

`removeAllObjects` will be marginally slower for a high number of objects than `initWithCapacity`. The real performance difference would be having to avoid growing the array when the number of objects reaches the limit.

As others pointed out, the objects are only released if there are no more strong references to them.

Comment: thanks... but if the size of my NSMutable array is 20mb with 10.000 elements for example... if I use the removeAllObjects method... its size will be 0mb?

Comment: Yes (if the objects held are not referenced from elsewhere). The array is not using 20MB storage, the objects held are. If you are using Xcode 5 you can see these things if you set a breakpoint, click on the memory gauge, and then click on Profile on Instruments. The memory being freed will be noticeable on the memory chart.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, it releases all the objects, it doesn't leak. (It doesn't, of course, explicitly deallocate them - they are only deallocated if the only reference to them was held by the array.)

Comment: When I saw the title of the question, this is the answer I had to check if anyone else had given.

Comment: if the size of my NSMutable array is 20mb with 10.000 elements for example... if I use the removeAllObjects method...will its size be 0mb?

Comment: @UsiUsi It depends on. You are confusing releasing an object with the deallocation of an object. The array will be empty after you send it this message, but no-one can guarantee that this action will actually free up some (if any) memory, since it may not only be the array that holds a reference to an object.

Comment: So to be sure that all the elements will free memory I must do something like this
[array release];

Comment: @UsiUsi No. In order to be sure that all the elements are freed, you must manage your memory properly, and they will be deallocated as soon as they are not needed anymore.

Answer (score 0):

No it does not leak objects. It is the same as removing every object individually except it is more convenient and faster.